# How to remove glare from images in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

This mathematica code removes glare from an image:

```
img = Import["foo.png"]
Inpaint[img, Dilation[saturated, DiskMatrix[20]]]
```

as shown in the most upvoted answer here:

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1215/how-to-remove-a-glare-clipped-brightness-from-an-image

I want to use opencv instead of Mathematica to get the same result. How would I write equivalent code in opencv-python?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), "What Are Good Topics" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What have you tried?  Look up the same functions in the OpenCV documentation. Try them and then if it does not work, post your attempt and question.

Comment: See morphology and inpaint at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/

Answer (score 5):

Here is how to do that in Python/OpenCV.

*But I do not think the OpenCV inpainting routines are working or at least are not working well for my Python 3.7.5 and OpenCV 3.4.8.*

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('apple.png')

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold grayscale image to extract glare
mask = cv2.threshold(gray, 220, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# Optionally add some morphology close and open, if desired
#kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (7,7))
#mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=1)
#kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
#mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)


# use mask with input to do inpainting
result = cv2.inpaint(img, mask, 21, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA) 

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("apple_mask.png", mask)
cv2.imwrite("apple_inpaint.png", result)

# display it
cv2.imshow("IMAGE", img)
cv2.imshow("GRAY", gray)
cv2.imshow("MASK", mask)
cv2.imshow("RESULT", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Thresholded image:

[image]

Result:

[image]